# Possible Security Issues On Web Layer Payment Request and Confirmation

Tags: events, interfaces, payments

This is more likely a design consultation rather than an issue.

I want to introduce additional standards in ISO20022 to promote crypto payment through common payment interface to eliminate 3rd party solution for fee processing and confirmation.

CAUTION: The design and idea has patent pending.

*Scenario:*
So the website customer finalize the order and execute the checkout where QR is generated and the blockchain listener is enabled waiting for event for specific *transactionId*. The customer scans the QR code and executes the payment from another website using his/her phone or on the same page with pop up interface. During the payment, a web wallet like Metamask will confirm the smart contract interaction, then when confirmed by the user, the smart contract `pay()` function will be executed, fund transfer is done and `Paid()` event is emitted and event listener is notified then payment is confirmed. This solution happens within the web layer and the blockchain.

Will there be any chance of hacking with this kind of solution? If so, what can you recommend?

```
interface ISO20022ForPaymentV1 {
    
    /**
     * @dev Call pay method to set specific payment information.
     * All input parameter can come from a QR code generated by
     * a specific terminal requesting and receiving a payment.
     */
    function pay(address stationAddress, 
                 uint256 paidAmount, 
                  string calldata transactionId, 
                  uint expiry,
                  string calldata payMeta)external returns(bool success);
    
    /**
     * @dev emit Paid event to notify subcribers waiting for payment.
     */
    event Paid(address indexed merchantAddress,
               address stationAddress,
               address indexed payeeAddress, 
               uint256 paidAmount, 
                string indexed transactionId, 
                string payMeta
            );
}
```

Implementation

```
 /**
    * @dev use case: A specific merchant cashier's terminal can get notified when a customer completes the payment.    * 
    */
    function pay(address stationAddress, uint256 amount, string calldata transactionId, uint expiry, string calldata payMeta)public override returns(bool success){
        require(expiry <=block.timestamp,'E56');
        require(_merchants[getParentAccount(stationAddress)].exist && bytes(transactionId).length <=256 && bytes(payMeta).length <= 256,'E39');
        _mTransfer(getParentAccount(stationAddress), amount);
        if(_mBalanceOf(msg.sender).sub(amount) >= _minHoldingForRefund && _refundPerTransaction > 0) _mRefund(msg.sender, _refundPerTransaction);
        emit Paid(getParentAccount(stationAddress), stationAddress, msg.sender, amount, transactionId, payMeta);
        return true;
    }
```